memcpy variant transforming and scaling larger data type into a smaller one. E.g., UINT16 to UINT8
I have got a large array of an unsigned data type T*.
It should be converted to unsigned char*, scaling values. E.g., when moving from unsigned short* to unsigned char* the range of {0,..,255} should be mapped to 0 and anything in {65281,..,65535} to 255.
Naively, this could be done in a loop, using something like a bit shift:
const T x = some_large_value;
unsigned char y = (x >> (8u * (sizeof(T) - 1u))); //<< Effectively a truncated "x/(256^{sizeof(t)-1})".

But I wonder, if there is a way to avoid the for (..) involved in such a solution. Dreaming of a super-memcpy supporting a step parameter that could be used like this:
// Intel processor. So I guess, little endian is needed. Assume there are N items.
const T* src = ..;
const unsigned char* src_uchar = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(src);
memcpy(dst_uchar, src_uchar + (sizeof(T) - 1u), N, step=sizeof(T)-1u);

That putative step-parameter would skip that many bytes after each copied byte. Sadly, of course, it does not exist. Yet is there some other command that allows for it or its effect?
Appendix: Adding a working demo program upon learning a solution
A glow of gratitude goes out to pptaszni. However, since it still took some processing of my own to understand: Here is a short demo program using his/her proposal. It does convert from an uint16 array to uint8, reducing the value range by grace of a bit shift. Works on signed types, too.
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        // Input A and Output B.
        const unsigned short A[] = {60000u, 50000u, 30000u, 1000u, 500u, 300u, 200u};
              unsigned char  B[] = {    0u,     0u,     0u,    0u,   0u,   0u,   0u};

        // lambda expression.
        auto transformation = [](const unsigned short& elem)
                { return static_cast<unsigned char>(elem >> 8u * (sizeof(decltype(elem))-1)); };

        // Actual downsizing of UINT16 to UINT8.
        std::transform(A, A+7, B, transformation);

        // Show the results.
        for (size_t j=0; j<7; ++j)
                { cout << A[j] << " => " << ((unsigned short)B[j]) << endl; }
        return 0;
}

Output:
60000 => 234
50000 => 195
30000 => 117
1000 => 3
500 => 1
300 => 1
200 => 0


What I need is to convert an array of values in, e.g., {0,..,,65535} to a linearly converted array in {0,..,255}, where the range of {0,..,255} is mapped to 0 and anything in {65281,..,65535} is mapped to 255. Byte order does not really factor into it, but would, of course, when tinkering with black magic like reinterpret_cast<..>, as I did in my second example code block (which does not work, due to lack of a real-life step parameter).

Simple std::transform wouldn't be good enough for you?

You have saturating 255 transformation/filter logic that just casts or implicit conversions do not do. You have to write function for it.

Feels like std::transform + std::back_inserter to me and let the compiler optimize (vectorize). Quick draft : https://godbolt.org/z/WK9YP4nWd. In any case, if you think you have a perfomance issue : Measure using a profiler... most likely your bottleneck is somewhere else (memory bandwidth, missed branch predictions etc)

@ptaszni: Thanks. Wasn't aware of that function std::transform. It boils down to a loop. Maybe something like it will be my answer after all.

@PepijnKramer I trust static_caststd::uint8_t(value) just slices bits out of original and does not saturate at 255.

A single operation looks like std::saturate_cast, however in order to properly vectorize it you'll probably need to write your own optimized implementation using assembly and/or intrinsics rather than hope for compiler.

@Markus-Hermann  the question is not too clear, if you want to map (16-bit, or 32-bit) data type to (8-bit) data type, do you want to map like this: 0xABCD -> 0xAB, 0xCD, or do you care about the last 8-bit only (most significant byte), and discard the extra? if you want to do this: 0xABCD -> 0xAB, 0xCD, it can be done using normal memcpy. and if you want to take the last 8-bit, do casting, casting will discard the extra bits.

@user7860670 C++26 features are not that widely available and if available should not be expected to be optimal. There are std::clamp, and std::ranges::clamp that might be better.

@ÖöTiib Well, it's one of those cases when a widely available routine finally gets into standard.

@ÖöTiib the cast was just a quick example, the actual lambda passed to transform should be modified to really match the expected output.

@Markus-Hermann memcpy also boils down to a loop. Unless you have more information about this large array that will help vectorization, everything will boil down to a loop.

Since both source and destination are unsigned, bind_front(ranges::min, numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max()) makes a good unary functor for ranges::transform. If C++20 is not available, drop bind_front and put std::min in a lambda as the unary functor for std::transform. Either way, stop using mem functions before you hit the UB wall.

What is wrong with for loop? You want to call one complex function with 10 parameters to avoid writing a loop?

In your case using std::transform might be good enough, even if not as fast as some tweaked version of std::memcpy could be. Assuming that your T --> std::uint8_t transformation function is:
auto transformation = [](const auto &elem) {
  return static_cast<std::uint8_t>(elem >>
                                   (8u * (sizeof(decltype(elem)) - 1u)));
};

An your buffers are:
using MyT = std::uint32_t;
// could be any container, also std::array, or a raw pointer (not with ranges)
std::vector<MyT> source_buff(LEN); // let's assume it's initialized with some data already
std::vector<std::uint8_t> dest_buff(LEN, 0);

You can simply write:
std::transform(source_buff.begin(), source_buff.end(), dest_buff.begin(),
               transformation);
// version with execution policy
std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq, source_buff.begin(),
               source_buff.end(), dest_buff.begin(), transformation);

Or using ranges:
auto transformedView = source_buff | std::views::transform(transformation);
// note that at this point no transformation took place yet, so you could defer iterating over the new range, or take only the results that you care about, e.g. transformedView[123]
std::ranges::copy(transformedView, std::ranges::begin(dest_buff));

When I benchmarked these 3 approaches (Ubuntu22 with gcc11 -O3) and compared it to classic for loop I got:
---------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                     Time             CPU   Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------------
JustLoop                 544408 ns       544363 ns         1425
StdTransform             133976 ns       133902 ns         4935
StdTransformParUnseq     143085 ns       143082 ns         4823
RangesTransform          134860 ns       134850 ns         5123

meaning that classic loop is the slowest, and using standard library algorithms allowed the compiler to use some fancy optimizations. Similar results using quickbench with Clang 17:


Thank you! Attempting to paraphrase: That transform lambda acts on UINT16, as does the iterator
that it is concerned with it. However, the output iterator acts on UINT8,
thus implicitly providing the "step" that I asked for in my question.
Will test that assumption, and, if finding it working, accept your answer. An upvote for the benchmarks and good explanation it deserves already.
